# Colouring cells in a table

Tags: tables, color

I am trying to create a table with specific cells coloured either green or red. As a trial, I used the following code to colour one cell green

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}
%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{optidef} 
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | } 
     \hline
      A & B & C \\
      \hline
      D & E & \cellcolor{green}F \\
      \hline
      G & H & I \\
      \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here I have used `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. This did not work, and the output generated is shown below

[image]

Is there a way to create a table with specific cell colours

Comment: If you use the package you state then the code you show produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p63UE.png) presumably you did not load the package (and got an error message) please post the error message not the output,

Comment: if you do not load `colortbl` (or `[table]{xcolor}` then you get the error `! Undefined control sequence. l.11   D & E & \cellcolor` and (if you scroll past the error) you get the output you show.

Comment: @MB have look at the answer below

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I just noticed that there is an error message "Underfined control sequence"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think one of my packages clashes with `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: your new version produces the error `! LaTeX Error: File \`mcode.sty' not found` that is not in texlive, can you give a link to it.

Comment: I would guess that mcode loads xcolor without th eoption, swap the order to load xcolor first.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are a genius. Swappy the order of the packages worked. I downloaded `mcode.sty` from [Mathworks](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package). Without it, my Matlab code looks very sloppy.

Comment: also, unrelated use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or better unless you have an old latex don't specify `inputenc` at all as utf-8 is the default,. (utf8x is a non standard variant option)

Comment: Note that it would have been totally impossible to answer your original question since the issue was completely in code you had not shown. No harm done but please always include full examples.

Comment: Note you would have had an error message about the option clash on xcolor , never ignore error messages

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Noted - I will do so next next. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mcode` is not in the standard distributions but you can see the same effect using `xcolor`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}
%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{optidef} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | }
      \hline
      A & B & C \\
      \hline
      D & E & \cellcolor{green}F \\
      \hline
      G & H & I \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

this produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
```

and if you scroll past that the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.24       D & E & \cellcolor
                             {green}F \\
?
```

as `\cellcolor` is not defined you get the output that you show.

Note that after *any* error the PDF output is not intended to be usable, it is at best, usable as a debugging aid. Never ignore error messages.

To fix the option clash, load `xcolor` earlier with the option, so simply swap the lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{extarticle}
%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{optidef} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | }
      \hline
      A & B & C \\
      \hline
      D & E & \cellcolor{green}F \\
      \hline
      G & H & I \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the command `\centering ` to center the table?

Comment: @MB yes of course

Comment: I updated my post. I placed the `tabular` environment within a `table` environment. The table is now centered, but it begins at the top of the page.

Comment: @MB  the site doesn't really support multiple questions asked in comments. that is the function of the table environment. It specifies the table may be moved.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|c|r}
  \hline
  Some & \cellcolor{blue!25}coloured & contents \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | }
    \hline
    A & B & C \\
    \hline
    D & E & \cellcolor{green}F \\
    \hline
    G & H & I \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Other than your first table, how is this different to my original code?

Comment: unless you would like to upload the complete code its difficult to say

Comment: It is in my original post. I copied and posted your second table, it produces the exact same output (see image in original post)

Comment: code should start with `begindocument` and finish at `enddocument` -- this is called a minimum working example or MWE-- the code uploaded above will not compile on its own -- that is why certain assumptions are made as to what is the desired output

Comment: I have updated my post. I have included every package that I am currently using, as well as `begindocument` and `enddocument`

Comment: I commented out the following line --- %\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode} -- and got the correct result --

Comment: There must be a clash. Unfortunately I need the `{mcode}` package to write Matlab code. Is there a way around this?

Comment: aah -- but you see this becomes a separate question -- that is why the emphasis on having the complete code in the first place-- I suggest you accept the answer to your original question -- if it met the requirement of the original question and for the mcode clash post a separate question