# `\rowcolor{}` does not color the row in a table

Tags: tables, rowcolor

My goal is to color a row as `lightgray`, but instead of coloring a row it just prints `green` string in the row. What my be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

I am using following example with additional packages such as [solidity-highlighting.tex](https://github.com/s-tikhomirov/solidity-latex-highlighting/blob/master/solidity-highlighting.tex), which contains `\usepackage{listings, xcolor}` on its first line.

Example is take [from](https://riptutorial.com/latex/example/20831/coloring-table):

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\input{solidity-highlighting.tex}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
   detect-mode,
   detect-family,
   detect-inline-family=math,
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | }
  \rowcolor{green}
  A & B & C \\
  \rowcolor{red}
  D & E & F \\
  G & H & I \\
  \rowcolor{blue}
  J & K & L
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please do not use external links, make a full example in the question, however an identical question was answered yesterday https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571498/colouring-cells-in-a-table/571501?noredirect=1#comment1440016_571501

Comment: In your full code, you load TikZ, which already loads `xcolor` without option, whence an option clash. Load `[table]` with the document class.

Comment: ...or shortly after `\documentclass` call `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}`.

Comment: @alper your question here is archived forever, so unless the code at the link will be there forever in a form that shows the problem it doesn't really improve the site to have such links.

Comment: @Werner Thanks it works. The clash was happening due to `\input{solidity-highlighting.tex} `,  which contains `\usepackage{listings, xcolor}` on its first line.